# Select first and nth order for each client

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to display first and fifth order_id for each user.

Table looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
| Order_ID | Client_ID | Datetime          |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1        | 1         | YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2        | 1         | YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3        | 2         | YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I wrote something like this:

```
select 
  t.client_id, 
  t.order_id as first_order, 
  t2.order_id as fifth_order,
  t.datetime as first_dt,
  t2.datetime as fifth_dt,
from
(
  select o.client_id, o.order_id, o.datetime,
  row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.datetime) as rn
  from "OhMyTable" as o
) as t
  left join
    (
  select o.client_id, o.order_id, o.datetime,
  row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.order_id) as rn
  from "OhMyTable" as o
      order by o.order_id
  ) as t2
  on t.client_id = t2.client_id
where t.rn = 1 and t2.rn = 5
```

But I want to see clients who made their first orders but don't have fifths. There should be NULL, but I can't understand how to make it. :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `where t2.rn = 5` condition into the `left join`:

```sql
select 
  t.client_id, 
  t.order_id as first_order, 
  t2.order_id as fifth_order,
  t.datetime as first_dt,
  t2.datetime as fifth_dt,
from
(
  select o.client_id, o.order_id, o.datetime,
  row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.datetime) as rn
  from "OhMyTable" as o
) as t
  left join
    (
  select o.client_id, o.order_id, o.datetime,
  row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.order_id) as rn
  from "OhMyTable" as o
      order by o.order_id
  ) as t2
  on t.client_id = t2.client_id
  and t2.rn = 5
where t.rn = 1 and t2.datetime is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If find that conditional aggregation is simpler than two subqueries for this. And you can use a `having` clause for filtering:

```
select client_id,
    max(order_id) filter(where rn = 1) first_order,
    max(order_id) filter(where rn = 5) fifth_order,
    min(datetime) first_dt,
    max(datetime) fifth_dt
from (
    select o.client_id, o.order_id, o.datetime,
        row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.datetime) as rn
    from "OhMyTable" as o
) t
where rn in (1, 5)
group by client_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select o.client_id,
       min(datetime) as first_datetime,
       max(datetime) as fifth_datime,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then order_id end) as first_orderid,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then order_id end) as fifth_orderid
from (select o.*
             row_number() over(partition by o.client_id order by o.datetime) as seqnum
      from "OhMyTable" o
     ) o
where seqnum in (1, 5);
```